# JFormattedTextField and PropertyChangeListener event.getOldValue() and event.getNewValue() returning null

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

As the title suggests, I have the following listener on a JFormattedTextField:

```
myFormattedTextField.addPropertyChangeListener("value", new PropertyChangeListener()
{
  @Override
  public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt)
  {
    System.out.println("Old value: " + evt.getOldValue());
    System.out.println("New value: " + evt.getNewValue());
  }
});
```

This always prints out null for both getOldValue() and getNewValue().
If I remove "value" string as a parameter, I get even weirder results, like the JPanel the textField is residing in or true/false values.

What exactly am I missing here?

Comment: I don't think that you're missing anything. The value for the field will be null until a new valid value has been entered.

Comment: Even after I change the text field and lose focus, it still returns null for both though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *What exactly am I missing here?*

It's hard to tell exactly what is the problem based on your snippet. However be aware that [JFormattedTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html) component works along with both an [AbstractFormatterFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatterFactory.html) and an [AbstractFormatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter.html) to be able to convert from a String representation to an Object value and the other way around.

If you initialize the formatted text field as follows, then both formatter and formatter factory will be `null` and no value could be ever converted: thus it will always be `null`:

```
JFormattedTextField textField = new JFormattedTextField(); // default empty constructor
```

If this is the case then you have an explanation about what is happening. If you take a look `JFormattedTextfield` class' constructors all of them take parameters that will help the component to initialize both formatter and formatter factory, except for empty constructor.

For a better understanding please have a look to [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html#constructors) tutorial.

#### Side note

You say in a comment:

> *I am not using a NumberFormatter. Since the text fields can be blank to start with.*

It's irrelevant if you want the text field be blank at the start: just don't set any value to the text field and leave the user change it (of course initial value will be `null`). But you definitely need to set a formatter.

Comment: Boom! Thanks, this was the issue.  I wasn't supplying a NumberFormatter Object.  Thanks much!!

Comment: @crumbug: which is exactly why you should have created and posted a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Next time, please allow us to answer without guessing. Good show dic. 1+

Answer (score 2):

if you are using `NumberFormatter` this may solve your problem:

```
numberFormatter.setCommitsOnValidEdit(true);
```

Comment: I am not using a NumberFormatter.  Since the text fields can be blank to start with.